# How to use a jack route as a single audio-filter with ffmpeg

Tags: filter, ffmpeg

I have configured **Ardour** and there,

- An audio track takes input from a `Jack-Sink` device
- Applies some effects by using some `Aux-Send`
- Outputs the final audio to `Master` which is a `Jack-Client`

Now, I want to use this whole route as a single audio filter something like how `lv2` can be used as a filter in `ffmpeg`.

That is, my virtual (expected) filter's input line is a `Jack-Sink`, output line is a `Jack-Client`.

Is there any such filter to use with ffmpeg ?